# How can I prevent a page render between changing scrollTop and CSS top in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, paint

[I've written a function to lock and unlock a page's scroll](https://gist.github.com/barneycarroll/6550066). The core mechanism relies on saving the HTML's `style` attribute and `scrollTop` property, changing `scrollTop` to 0, and applying the saved `scrollTop` as a negative CSS `top` and `position: fixed`.

Everything's working to satisfaction (allowing for a few edge cases), [as you can see on this demo](http://barneycarroll.com/bugs/jquery.scrollLock.js/#).

The problem is that in IE8 and below, there's a flicker during unlocking between reinstating the styles and the `scrollTop` property in lines 138 to 144:

```
// Revert styles
$html.attr( 'style', $( '<x>' ).css( prevStyles ).attr( 'style' ) || '' );

// Revert scroll values
$( window )
    .scrollLeft( prevScroll.scrollLeft )
    .scrollTop(  prevScroll.scrollTop );
```

I'm surprised that a browser known for jerky frame rates and slow processing finds the time and resources to re-paint the page between consecutive lines of Javascript, when Chrome, Firefox apparently wait til the stack clears before applying the code.

How can I stop IE from painting the page in between these two statements?

Comment: Have you tried, instead, using the block scroll method where you set the height of the body to the height of the window and do overscroll hidden? Not sure why IE8 is doing that, but maybe another way of blocking is worth a shot?

Comment: @Oscar I'd be interested to see that method in action. My immediate concerns are that you'd lose the `scrollTop` position and the scrollbar (thereby changing layout). Can you think of anywhere this technique is implemented?

Comment: Yammer and Facebook. Facebook actually sets the height to 0. Yammer does the overflow:hidden trick. You wouldn't "lose" the scrolltop. Your scrollTop should be the same. You're not touching scrollTop just cutting the page's height down.

Comment: @Oscar thanks very much for the tip. The solution appears a lot cleaner at first sight, but sadly (as far as I can work out) reinstating the document `scrollTop` is still necessary upon unlocking, meaning the intermittent flickr remains in IE8. Given that the fixed wrapper method makes more assumptions about markup and CSS, I may stick with my current method…